# Filter table data in memory without making a new api request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js and looking for a way to search the data in the Table.

I just want to search on the table data that is rendered in the UI without calling any API.

Search using EmpName.

Below is the code:

```
import { ReactElement, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
components
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import SearchInput from "./components/Form/SearchInput";
import Layout from "./components/layouts/Layout";
import useSWR from "swr";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  return { props: {} };
};

interface Employee {
  id: string;
  emp_name: string;
  emp_address: string;
  emp_pay: string;
}


const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function Page() {
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");

  const { data: emps, isLoading } = useSWR<Employee[]>(
    "/api/emp/list",
    fetcher
  );
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const tableHeaders: empColumn[] = useMemo(() => {
    return [
     //Header Data
    ];
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Stack spacing={6}>
        <Flex justifyContent="space-between" columnGap={3}>
          <Heading size="lg">Employees</Heading>
          <HStack spacing={3}>
            <SearchInput
              width={280}
              value={searchString}
              onChange={setSearchString}
            />
          </HStack>
        </Flex>
        {isLoading ? (
          <Center>
            <Spinner />
          </Center>
        ) : (
          <TableContainer>
            <Table size="sm" mt="10">
              <Thead>
                <Tr>
                  {tableHeaders.map((header) => (
                    <Td key={header.key}>{header.title}</Td>
                  ))}
                </Tr>
              </Thead>
              <Tbody>
                {(emps || []).map((emp) => (
                  <Tr key={emp.id}>
                    {tableHeaders.map((header) => (
                      <Td
                        key={`${emp.id}_${header.key}`}
                        whiteSpace="nowrap"
                        maxWidth={300}
                        overflow="hidden"
                        textOverflow="ellipsis"
                      >
                        {emp[header.key]}
                      </Td>
                    ))}
                  </Tr>
                ))}
              </Tbody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        )}
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}

Page.getLayout = (page: ReactElement) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
```

How could I filter the existing emps and show filtered list in table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array you are rendering, according to what has been typed in the search input, like so:

```
{(emps || [])
  .filter(emp.emp_name.includes(searchString)) // update the filter logic as you need
  .map((emp) => (
    <Tr key={emp.id}>
      {tableHeaders.map((header) => (
        <Td
          key={`${emp.id}_${header.key}`}
          whiteSpace="nowrap"
          maxWidth={300}
          overflow="hidden"
          textOverflow="ellipsis"
        >
          {emp[header.key]}
        </Td>
      ))}
    </Tr>
  ))}
```